# LineSDK Use LoginConfiguration before setup. Please call `LoginManager.setup` before you do any other things in LineSDK

Tags: ios, react-native, line, file-not-found

## package.json

```
 "@xmartlabs/react-native-line": "^2.2.0",
 "react": "18.2.0",
 "react-native": "0.72.6",
```

1.https://www.npmjs.com/package/@xmartlabs/react-native-line?activeTab=readme Installed for android it works fine but for ios there is an error.

Thread 1: Fatal error: [LineSDK] Use LoginConfiguration before setup. Please call `LoginManager.setup` before you do any other things in LineSDK.

2.install Inside your `AppDelegate.m` error 'rnline-swift.h' file not found

**How can I solve this problem?**

**pod file**

````
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] = podfile_properties['newArchEnabled'] == 'true' ? '1' : '0'
ENV['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR'] = podfile_properties['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR']

def node_require(script)
  # Resolve script with node to allow for hoisting
  require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
    "require.resolve(
      '#{script}',
      {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
    )", __dir__]).strip
end

node_require('react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb')
node_require('react-native-permissions/scripts/setup.rb')

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.4'
install! 'cocoapods',
  :deterministic_uuids => false

prepare_react_native_project!

setup_permissions([
  'Camera',
  'LocationAlways',
  'LocationWhenInUse',
  'Notifications',
  'PhotoLibrary',
])
pod 'lottie-ios'
pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'
rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...), which will be excluded. To fix this,
# you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` in `react-native.config.js`
#
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
#   }
# }
# ```
flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.disabled
if ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == '1' then
  # Explicitly disabled through environment variables
  flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.disabled
elsif podfile_properties.key?('ios.flipper') then
  # Configure Flipper in Podfile.properties.json
  if podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] == 'true' then
    flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug", "Release"])
  elsif podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] != 'false' then
    flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.enabled(["Debug", "Release"], { 'Flipper' => podfile_properties['ios.flipper'] })
  end
end

target 'sktconnect' do
  use_expo_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']
  use_frameworks! :linkage => ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS'].to_sym if ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == nil || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    :hermes_enabled => false,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work if enabled
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config
  )

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

    # This is necessary for Xcode 14, because it signs resource bundles by default
    # when building for devices.
      installer.target_installation_results.pod_target_installation_results
        .each do |pod_name, target_installation_result|
        target_installation_result.resource_bundle_targets.each do |resource_bundle_target|
          resource_bundle_target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings["CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES"] = true
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
            config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
            config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
          end
        end
      end
      installer.aggregate_targets.first.user_project.native_targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS'] = ['$(inherited)', '$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift']
        end
      end
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if (target.name&.eql?('FBReactNativeSpec'))
          target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
            if (build_phase.respond_to?(:name) && build_phase.name.eql?('[CP-User] Generate Specs'))
              target.build_phases.move(build_phase, 0)
            end
          end
        end
      end
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end
end
````